# How do I handle this error for Hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, python, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I am getting the following error using Hamcrest Matcher library.

> "The method assertThat(T, Matcher) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (List, AnyOf)"

What I am trying is
Sample code

```
List<String> poster_path_image2;         
assertThat(poster_path_image2, anyOf(startsWith("https:"), startsWith("null")));
```

I need to check if a url is valid and null value is acceptable as well.
I am new to this library and stumped by this error.

Comment: What is the type of `poster_path_image2`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `poster_path_image2` is of type `List`. but the Matcher `startsWith` can just work on `String`. Check the types of your variables and what the matcher is able to process.

Maybe you want to get the first element of your List or repeat the assertion for every item in the list.

```
String path = "your test String";       
assertThat(path, anyOf(startsWith("https:"), is(nullValue())));
```

I changed the second matcher as I think you want the check if your String is `null` and not if it contains the String value `"null"`.